# A `dispose pattern` in C#: why do we need `if (disposing)` condition?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable, finalizer

So, the default *dispose pattern* implementation looks like this:

```
class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
   // Flag: Has Dispose already been called?
   bool disposed = false;

   // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
   public void Dispose()
   { 
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);           
   }

   // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (disposed)
         return; 

      if (disposing) {
         // Free any other managed objects here.
      }

      // Free any unmanaged objects here.
      disposed = true;
   }

   ~SomeClass()
   {
      Dispose(false);
   }
}
```

It's said that:

> If the method call comes from a finalizer (that is, if disposing is
>   `false`), only the code that frees unmanaged resources executes. Because
>   the order in which the garbage collector destroys managed objects
>   during finalization is not defined, calling this `Dispose` overload with
>   a value of `false` prevents the finalizer from trying to release managed
>   resources that may have already been reclaimed.

**The question is:** why is it supposed that the objects that are referenced by the object of `SomeClass` may already have been freed and we shouldn't try to dispose them when the method is called from the finalizer? If those objects are still referenced by our `SomeClass` object they cannot be freed, isn't it true?  It's said that:

> Those with pending (unrun) finalizers are kept alive (for now) and are
>   put onto a special queue. [...] Prior to each object’s finalizer
>   running, **it’s still very much alive — that queue acts as a root**
>   **object**.

So, again, our `SomeClass` object is referenced by this queue (which is the same as to be referenced by a root). And other objects the `SomeClass` object has references to should be alive as well (as they are rooted through the `SomeClass` object). **Then why and how they might have been freed by the time the `SomeClass` finalizer is called?**

Comment: Just to throw a spanner-in-the-works here, you should basically never use finalizers, there is a good chance if you are using one, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Actually here is a post by *Stephen Cleary* [IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About) it answers everything you want to know, and everything else you didn't know you needed to know (fun level 100)

Comment: don't bother if you don't have unmanaged resources since you wont need finalizer

Comment: I think the bigger point and one of the biggest "rules" about Finalizers (other than #1: don't) is that they shouldn't touch/access/use any managed objects. The guard is there to ensure you only interact with unmanaged objects if the method was initiated from the finalizer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Konrad Kokosa has an impressive explanation on his book [Pro .NET Memory Management](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KGKGK8K).
(emphasis added)

> During GC, at the end of Mark phase, GC checks the finalization queue to see if any of the finalizable objects are dead. If they are some, **they cannot be yet delete because their finalizers will need to be executed**. Hence, such object is **moved to yet another queue called fReachable queue**. Its name comes from the fact that it represents finalization reachable objects - **the ones that are now reachable only because of finalization**. If there are any such objects found, GC indicates to the dedicated finalizer thread there’s work to do.
>
> **Finalization thread** is yet another thread created by the.NET runtime. **It removes objects from the fReachable queue one by one and calls their finalizers**. This happens after GC resumes managed threads because finalizer code may need to allocate objects. **Since the only root to this object is removed from the fReachable queue, the next GC that condemns the generation this object is in will find it to be unreachable and reclaim it.**
>
> Moreover, **fReachable queue is treated as a root considered during Mark phase because the finalizer thread may not be fast enough to process all objects from it between GCs**. This exposes the finalizable objects more to a Mid-life crisis - they may stay in fReachable queue for a while consuming generation 2 just because of pending finalization.

I think the key here is:

> fReachable queue is treated as a root considered during Mark phase because the finalizer thread may not be fast enough to process all objects from it between GCs.

Comment: So, if this queue is considered to be similar to root and **"Since the only root to this object is removed from the fReachable queue, the next GC that condemns the generation this object is in will find it to be unreachable and reclaim it."** It's said **the next GC that condemns"** - not the current one. Doesn't this mean that internal objects can't be disposed before their owner and we can safely call the Dispose method on each of them from their owner method in any scenario (including call from finalizer)?

Comment: Yes, but objects in the fReachable queue have this only one root (the queue itself). They are processed one by one, without trying to process them in any order resulting from objects referencing each other - this could require discovering quite complex ordering. And what with circular references then?

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, the ownership relationship no longer matters. IOW all relations are broken and each object on its own in this queue. I did not mean circular references, but in the end, it turns out that the approach to all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in .NET exist while any references exist to them.  They cease to exist as soon as the last reference does so.  Storage used by an object will never be reclaimed while the object exists, but there are a couple of things the GC does before it reclaims storage:

1. There is a special list, called the "finalizer queue", which holds references to all objects which have registered finalizers.  After identifying every other reference that exists anywhere in the universe, the GC will examine all objects in the finalizer queue to see if any references have been found to them.  If this process causes it to find an object which had not been discovered previously, it copies a reference to another list called the "freachable queue".  Any time the freachable queue is non-empty and no finalizer is running, the system will pull a reference from that queue and call finalize upon it.
2. The GC will also inspect the targets of all weak references and invalidate any weak reference whose target hadn't been identified by any live strong reference.

Note that a finalize method does not "garbage-collect" an object.  Instead, it prolongs the existence of the object until `finalize` is called upon it, *for purpose of allowing it to satisfy any obligations it might have to outside entities*.  If at that time no reference to the object exists anywhere in the universe, the object will cease to exist.

Note that it's possible for two objects with finalizers to hold references to each other.  In such situations, the order in which their finalizers run is unspecified.

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand it quite well. Is your point that objects referenced by an object that is currently finalizing might be finalized before their parent despite the references they have from it?

Comment: I'm reading "C# 7.0 in a Nutshell" and can't see any explanation of it in there. And I couldn't find any docs on it with this aspect explained. Could you share a link to the doc on it?

Comment: @Sergey: I don't have the link handy, but I think searching "freachable queue" should offer some insights.  A key point is that finalization is triggered by the GC, but the actual calls to `finalize` aren't part of the GC process and there's nothing special about when the time `finalize` runs beyond the lack of guarantees about it.  It's entirely possible that by the time the system gets around to running a finalizer, some other object's finalizer may have stored a strong reference to the former object in a place accessible to "normal" code, which could have started using it.